# How to prevent click event to propagate to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't really explain it so I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9tm5dtf/) but as you can see when you open the menu by clicking the `toggleButton` and you click the div `removeBtn` and that removes the item but the slide toggle is activated because of it...

I'm not using the conventional click slidetoggle because I'd like the `mainMenu` to close if the user clicks outside of the div...

Any idea why?

Comment: M'sieur's answer will fix your issue, however, the problem lies in that you're catching all clicks inside the document which includes your `.remove()` call.

Comment: @Press : You may be right. I think Jamie did this to close the slideUp menu if the user clicks outside of the toggle button. It may not be the clearest implementation, but we must admit it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent propagation of the click event :

```
$('#removeBtn').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
});
```

Comment: You forgot to add the `e` in the function parameters list. `function(e){...}`. See http://jsfiddle.net/m9tm5dtf/2/

Comment: Ahh yup that fixed it. Cheers.